# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on a file I cannot find?

Tags: python, shutil

I have a problem using copying a file with the shutil.copy2 method.

An error is raised after running this code:

```
source_dir = r'G:\Ma Musique'
dest_dir = r'H:\All my music'

def copy_all_files(source_dir,destination_dir):
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            shutil.copy2(path, destination_dir) 


copy_all_files(source_dir,dest_dir)
```

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'H:\\All my music\\AlbumArtSmall.jpg'
```

The thing is that when I make a research on AlbumArtSmall.jpg I cannot find it either in my source or destination directory.So I can't even check what permission this file has ...

More precision:

I'm trying to copy .mp3 file that may have an Album art jpeg into this audio file but how find it and modify its permission?

I'm using Windows 7, Python 3.7, launching python script from Notepad ++

Edit: I changed the OS from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and it worked.

Comment: The error is on `H:`, not `G:`, therefore it's a _write_ permission error, not a _read_ permission error.  Doubke-check that you have write permission for `H:\All my music`.

Comment: _AlbumArtSmall.jpg I cannot find it either in my source or destination directory_ It must be there somewhere, or the script would not try to copy it.  Perhaps it's in a subdirectory of `G:\Ma Musique`?  In the inner loop, add a `print(path)` statement before `shutil.copy`, so you can see the full source path.

Comment: I change OS and Python version and the script seems to work fine on a Linux distribution (Ubuntu) that displays the file AlbumArtSmall.jpg in the file explorer and has no problem copying this file from one location to another. this error was apparently caused by the OS I was using which doesn't handle permission the same way Linux does...

Comment: On UNIX, you need `+x` on any directory you want to traverse through, so you can get that error if you don't have execute on the `All my music` directory.